# Convert each dataframe row to Object in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe:

```
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬
│ Name      ┆ Purchase   ┆ Size       ┆ Color      ┆
│           ┆ Time       ┆            ┆            ┆
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆            ┆
│ str       ┆ datetime[μ ┆ i64        ┆ ---        ┆
│           ┆ s]         ┆            ┆ str        ┆
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪
│ T-Shirt   ┆ 2022-02-14 ┆ 12         ┆ Blue       ┆
│           ┆ 14:40:09.1 ┆            ┆            ┆
│           ┆ 00         ┆            ┆            ┆
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────
```

And I would like to convert each row of this dataframe into an object which contains information extracted from the rows, e.g:
PurchasedObject(Name, Size, Color)

Is it possible with polars to create a new column in the dataframe, which contains for each row the corresponding object?

Which would be the best way to achieve this in Polars?
Thank you!

Comment: did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Polars has a `struct` datatype that can be used to pack columns together in a single datatype.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["t-shirt"],
    "purchased": [datetime(2022, 2, 4)],
    "size": [12],
    "color": ["blue"]
}).with_column(
    pl.struct(["name", "size", "color"]).alias("purchased_struct")
)
```

```
shape: (1, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬───────┬───────────────────────┐
│ name    ┆ purchased           ┆ size ┆ color ┆ purchased_struct      │
│ ---     ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---                   │
│ str     ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  ┆ str   ┆ struct[3]             │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ t-shirt ┆ 2022-02-04 00:00:00 ┆ 12   ┆ blue  ┆ {"t-shirt",12,"blue"} │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴───────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: But then how can I convert the struct column into a column of object of type PurchasedObject? I could do this by reading row by row and converting everything, but that would be super inefficient.. @ritchie46

Comment: What is a `type PurchasedObject`? A `python` object? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is a python object that I created. The use case that I have to save the row as python objects (I have various types of objects and dataframes), and then based on the object, we will serialize it as json and then store it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add new column `PurchasedObject` to the dataframe `df`, here is how it can be done.

```
df.with_columns(
    df\
    .to_struct('PurchasedObject')\
    .apply(lambda person: PurchasedObject(Name=person['Name'], Size=person['Size'], Color=person['Color']))
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (1, 5)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Name    ┆ Purchase Time           ┆ Size ┆ Color ┆ PurchasedObject                     │
│ ---     ┆ ---                     ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---                                 │
│ str     ┆ datetime[μs]            ┆ i64  ┆ str   ┆ object                              │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ T-Shirt ┆ 2022-02-14 14:40:09.100 ┆ 12   ┆ Blue  ┆ Name='T-Shirt' Size=12 Color='Bl... │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```